# How to check if value exists in python list of objects

Tags: python, list, object, dictionary

if i have a simple list objects:

```
shapes = [
  {
    'shape': 'square',
    'width': 40,
    'height': 40
  },
  {
    'shape': 'rectangle',
    'width': 30,
    'height': 40

  }
]
```

How can i quickly check if a `shape` with value `square` exists? I know I can use a `for` loop to check each object, but is there a faster way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `any(shape.get('shape') == 'square' for shape in shapes)`

Comment: Why do you assume that a for loop is slow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look ma, no loop.

```
import json
import re

if re.search('"shape": "square"', json.dumps(shapes), re.M):
    ... # "square" does exist
```

If you want to retrieve the index associated with `square`, you'd need to iterate over it using `for...else`:

```
for i, d in enumerate(shapes):
    if d['shape'] == 'square':
        break
else:
    i = -1

print(i)
```

---

**Performance**

```
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.5 µs per loop   # regex
1000000 loops, best of 3: 341 ns per loop   # loop
```

Comment: How is the performance here ? Can you please provide performance comparison with the for loop solution

Comment: @SarathSadasivanPillai Oh, there's absolutely no comparison. A loop is by far faster than a regex. I think OP accepted my answer because of the second part of my answer, not the first.

Comment: Test mine, test mine - `'square' in map(operator.itemgetter('shape'), shapes)`

Comment: Different machine/cpu/speed --> apples and oranges.  Thankyouverymuch.

Comment: Although simple, this solution throws an error with any non-JSON serializable objects. Even when the objects are serializable, it can be hacked: https://repl.it/KtXT/0

Comment: @EricZhang Good catch! I definitely did not consider that when writing the first option.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ exactly, I was wondering if there is any interpreter level optimisations improve the performance of regex as the expression can be resolved to substring search as OP accepted it LOLs

Answer (score 22):

You can do this in one line with the builtin function `any`:

```py
if any(obj['shape'] == 'square' for obj in shapes):
    print('There is a square')
```

This is equivalent to the for-loop approach, though.

---

If you need to get the index instead, then there is still a one-liner that can do this without sacrificing efficiency:

```py
index = next((i for i, obj in enumerate(shapes) if obj['shape'] == 'square'), -1)
```

However, this is complicated enough that it's probably better to just stick with a normal for loop.

```py
index = -1
for i, obj in enumerate(shapes):
    if obj['shape'] == 'square':
        index = i
        break
```

Comment: perfect! following that approach, is there a way to quickly return the index of that shape as well?

Answer (score 3):

Using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) you can do:

```
if [item for item in shapes if item['shape'] == 'square']:
    # do something
```

Using [filter()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter):

```
if list(filter(lambda item: item['shape'] == 'square', shapes)):
    # do something
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, using `get` for a more robust solution:

```
if any(i.get("shape", "none") == "square" for i in shapes):
    #do something
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Checking only if it exists:

```
any(shape.get('shape') == 'square' for shape in shapes)
```

Getting first index (you will get StopIteration exception if it does not exist).

```
next(i for i, shape in enumerate(shapes) if shape.get('shape') == 'square')
```

All indexes:

```
[i for i, shape in enumerate(shapes) if shape.get('shape') == 'square']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import operator
shape = operator.itemgetter('shape')
shapez = map(shape, shapes)
print('square' in shapez)
```